# Search a json key by closest match python

Tags: python, json

I was trying to learn how I can search through json key pairs by its closest match. So I did some google searching and got to here: https://linuxhint.com/search_json_python/

Eventually, I copied and pasted the example 3 code into my idle and it works but if I type anything other than an exact match (for example `Pe` instead of `Pen`) it will raise the exception.

I essentially want to find a why to print the results of a search of anything that wasn't a match but was close. (kind of like when using os.walk)

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Import json module
import json

# Define json variable
jsondata = """[
 {
  "name":"Pen",
  "unit_price":5
 },
 {
  "name":"Eraser",
  "unit_price":3
 },
 {
  "name":"Pencil",
  "unit_price":10
 },
 {
  "name":"White paper",
  "unit_price":15
 }
]"""

# load the json data
items = json.loads(jsondata)

# Input the item name that you want to search
item = input("Enter an item name:\n")

# Define a function to search the item
def search_price (name):
 for keyval in items:
  if name.lower() == keyval['name'].lower():
   return keyval['unit_price']

# Check the return value and print message
if (search_price(item) != None):
  print("The price is:", search_price(item))
else:
  print("Item is not found")
```

Any ideas or links would be much appreciated.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: `next(filter(lambda x: x["name"].startswith(item), items))` or `next(x for x in items if x["name"].startswith(item))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Olvin Roght was able to give me the correct answer that helped:`next(filter(lambda x: x["name"].startswith(item), items)) or next(x for x in items if x["name"].startswith(item))`

Answer (score 0):

```
def search_price (name):
 for keyval in items:
  if name.lower() in keyval['name'].lower():
   return keyval['unit_price']
```

try this please.